# Domain name points to different IPs from different locations

Tags: ip, ping, domain-name

I'm having this problem that seems odd to me. I have a domain name (`www.arioo.com`) which must point to the IP, `173.45.102.106`. It's ok when I try to reach it from my local PC or every other network that I have physical access to.
The problem occurs when I try to ping the domain from it's own server using ssh! The domain name points to a completely different IP address.

I wonder if this is caused by DNS caching since we had a server change almost a month ago, in which case that should be odd too for taking this long to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you have the server ping itself? Anyway, the A record looks fine to me, so try doing a dig of the domain from the server again. If it's still pointing elsewhere and you haven't set a ridiculously long TTL or updated name servers in the last couple of days, then the problem lies with what DNS servers your server is querying.

Comment: I was essentially trying to use `wget` in crontab for some php script to run periodically when I found out about this problem. So is there any way to know what DNS servers are being used?

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

- your resolver might give you a special "view" on the DNS database
  (more details in the BIND manual: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html)
- your /etc/hosts file might have a manual entry

Answer (score 0):

I'd also look at what settings you have in your /etc/nsswitch file.  This controls the order of hostname/IP lookups.  Make sure it is in the order you want them.

One other thing, try restarting (or disabling) the nscd service.  I have found that in several instances it causes the wrong result to be returned.

Take a look at the DNSen you are pointing to on your host (/etc/resolv.conf).  If you are using a broken DNS then you might be having problems.